# Property private set not firing NotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: wpf, vb.net

So this is more a question but can someone tell me why if i create a property like:

```
 Private _Productgroepen As ObservableCollection(Of productgroep)
    Public Property Productgroepen As ObservableCollection(Of productgroep)

        Get
            Return _Productgroepen
        End Get
        Private Set(ByVal value As ObservableCollection(Of productgroep))
            _Productgroepen = value
            MyBase.OnPropertyChanged("Productgroepen")
        End Set

    End Property
```

the "Private set" is not getting fire in the same way as using just "set"? So basicly im working on one pc and my co-worked on another one, on his pc the property works just fine, but on my pc the property is not getting any value at all! Can some one explain that to me?

Thanks

EDIT:
To anwser the first comment on this post here it goes:
The property "Productgroepen" is getting values from the constructor of the viewmode:

```
Public sub New()
    Dim pg = (from prg in db.producgroep).Tolist
    For each pgs in pg
        Productgroepen.add(pgs)
    Next
End sub
```

On xaml i have a combobox with:

```
... ItemsSouce={"Binding Productgroepen"} DisplayMemberPath="omschrijving" SelectedValue={"Binding SelectedProductgroepen", updatesourcetrigger=propertychanged} ..
```

So basicly on my pc when im debugging i get no errors or exception but the combobox doenst get any values if i have the setter on private BUT on my buddy pc he has no errors or exception and the combobox has all the values(he has also the setter on private).. 
If anyone knows why this behavor let me know, im always open to learn more.

Comment: you may already know this, but just want to bring it to your notice.. if property has private setter then you cannot do 2 way binding with that property.. because for XAML file the private setter is not exposed. if this is not the case then adding some more information like from where you are setting value for "Productgroepen" may help to give better answer

Comment: Edited post with some more code

Comment: I have noticed you are adding values to observable collection in a for loop, but what i need is where you are creating instance for that ObservableCollection (Productgroepen). Adding items to observable collection will not fire the setter. I suspect you are creating instance for "_Productgroepen" instead of "Productgroepen". if so change your code to create instance for "Productgroepen" that will call your setter.

Comment: The instance is created on the constructor, i didnt add all the code i have on the costructor but i expected you could understant, im doing something like:_Productsubgroep = new Observablecollection(of productsubgroep). And the i fill then productsubgroep property on the for loop.